# how to make my addbutton add a new textfield or dropdownbutton to my listview on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[I want this to be add to my list view on pressed add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GczBj.png)

[To be add on a row here on my list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBPjy.png)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: when i press the add button i want it to add the value of my dropdownbutton and the value of my textfield to my listview in a row

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) and a [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).
2. Update two lists with [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).

Comment: i want a textfield and a dropdownbutton to be added on my listview when i press the add button on a row format, lol.